# Can anyone suggest a quick fix for the error I am getting in L shape matrix traversal?

Tags: python, matrix, traversal

I want to traverse my matrix in the L shape, and I took the code from this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/traverse-matrix-in-l-shape/. However, it throws an index out-of-range error with input values when `rows = 3` and `cols = 9`.

```
# Printing matrix in L shape
def traverseLshape(a, n, m):
    
    # for each column or each L shape
    for j in range(0, m):

        # traversing vertically
        for i in range(0, n - j):
            print(a[i][j], end = " ")

        # traverse horizontally
        for k in range(j + 1, m):
            print(a[n - 1 - j][k], end = " ")

# Driven Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 3
    m = 9
    a = [[0, 6, 3, 4, 4, 6 ,1, 4 ,1],
         [5, 4 ,0, 3, 4 , 6, 6, 3, 2],
         [4 ,3, 6, 3 ,2, 4, 2, 6, 5]]
    traverseLshape(a, n, m);
```

expected output:`0 5 4 3 6 3 2 4 2 6 5 6 4 0 3 4 6 6 3 2 3 4 4 6 1 4 1`

actual output: `0 5 4 3 6 3 2 4 2 6 5 6 4 0 3 4 6 6 3 2 3 4 4 6 1 4 1 2 4 2 6 5 6 6 3 2 1 4 1`
`print(a[n - 1 - j][k], end = " ");`

Error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If m>n, then `range(0, n - j)` with j in `[0,m)` may be `range(0,0)` or even `range(0,-?)`. Which is empty. That is not your main problem. Since then `for i in range(0,n-j)` will just do nothing. But just noting it, because it is obviously not wanted.

But more importantly, `a[n - 1 - j][k]` when j is `m-1` (its biggest value) would be `a[n-1-(m-1)]` aka `a[n-m]` which is negative.

So, first time, not a big deal, just wrong values. Since `a[-1]` is the same as `a[len(a)-1]`.

Reason why, once it should have stopped, that is one you have printed all the elements but the 1st of last row (`a[2,k]`→`3, 6, 3 ,2, 4, 2, 6, 5`), then all elements but the 2 first of second row (`a[1,k]`→`0, 3, 4 , 6, 6, 3, 2`), then all elements but the 3 first of the first row (`a[0,k]`→`4, 4, 6 ,1, 4 ,1`), (not mentioning the elements of columns: `0,5,4`, then `6,4`, then `3`, in between),

you wrongly continue with all the elements but the 4 first of the last row (`a[-1][k]` → `2, 4, 2, 6, 5`); then all elements but the 5 first of the 2nd row (`a[-2][k]`→`6, 6, 3, 2`); then all elements but the 6 first of the first row (`a[-3][k]`→`1, 4 ,1`).

And then, it fails, because `a[-4][k]` is out of bound.